# while() loop runs indefinitely; the condition won't change; .replace() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a **letter** with a **white space** `" "` inside a word using the following JS code:

```
let letter = document.querySelector("#letter").value.toLowerCase();
var word = "letters";
var i = word.indexOf(letter);
console.log("word[i]: " + word[i]);
while(i > -1) {
    console.log(i);
    word.replace(word[i], " ");
    console.log("word: " + word);
    i = word.indexOf(letter);
    console.log(i);
}
console.log("word after: " + word);
```

**The problem** is that `i` stays 2 and won't change. `word.replace(word[i], " ");` doesn't seem to do its job.

I thought of that loop to go like this:

- let's say `letter` is `t`
- `var i` will first be `2`
- `word.replace(word[i], " ");` will replace the character at `word[2]` with a white space
- `word` will become `le ters`
- `i = word.indexOf(letter);` will then find the next `t` on `3`
- `word.replace(word[i], " ");` will replace the character at `word[]` with a white space
- `word` will become `le  ers`
- now `i` should become `-1` because there aren't anymore `t` in `word` and exit the `while` loop

The problem is that it doesn't work like that. The `while` loop is running indefinitely and `i` stays 2.

What is the problem ?

Comment: strings are immutable. `replace` returns a new string which you need to reassign. `word = word.replace(...)`. You can also use regex to do this without while: `word.replace(new RegExp(letter ,"g"), " ")`

Comment: Could you present your question in terms of "given input X, then the desired output is Y, but problem Z occurs in this code"?

Comment: @adiga `word = word.replace(word[pos], "");` works nicely. The regex solution sounds even better. but needs a little bit more research on my end. Thanks !

Comment: @adiga `word = word.replace(new RegExp(letter ,"g"), "");` works wonders and is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `/t/g`

**Check snippet:**

```js
//let replace = document.querySelector("#letter").value.toLowerCase();
var replace = "t";
var re = new RegExp(replace,"g");

var original_text="letters";
var extracted_text = original_text.replace(re, ' ');
console.log(extracted_text);
```

Comment: But how can I use regex with variables ? You've put `t` inside `/t/g`. I want to put `letter` which is `let letter = document.querySelector("#letter").value.toLowerCase();`

Comment: updated my code, are you able to upvote and mark as correct after closing your question?

Comment: `word = word.replace(new RegExp(letter ,"g"), "");` works wonders and is much cleaner than my `while` loop.